# checking for failed new

Tags: com, atl, new-operator, allocator

why does this ATL/COM code check for successful alloc? I would have expected a custom allocation to be visible through CoGetALloc or some such api. A standards-conforming C++ runtime should be throwing std::bad_alloc, but then again maybe the allocator has indeed been traded out for a non-throwing impl.

```
DDClientData* pNewData = new DDClientData();
if (pNewData==NULL)
    return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COM methods are not allowed to let exceptions out - the implementation can throw exceptions, but it must handle them before they escape the method and translate to an appropriate HRESULT.

The code above will not have desired effect - once `new` fails `std::bad_alloc` is thrown and the check for a null pointer is not executed. The implementation has to either wrap the `new` call into `try`-`catch` or wrap the whole method implementation into `try`-`catch`. ATL usually uses [_ATLTRY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799wd5bd(VS.80).aspx)-like macros around the `new` call.

Answer (score 1):

COM doesn't use exceptions: any COM object is supposed to return a valid `HRESULT` on failure. Plus there are guarantees about setting return values on exit, which any conforming COM object has to comply with. For these reasons, exceptions play badly with COM/ATL, and aren't used at all internally at Microsoft[1], not even for allocations. The code sample shown above simply reflects that convention.

[1] Sez me, an MS FTE. COM components at MS are compiled with C++ exceptions disabled.

Comment: so, since im compiling with exceptions on, the code is redundant.